# Font style in Mathematica matching \mathcal and \mathbf in Miktex

Tags: fonts, latex, webmathematica

In Mathematica I plot

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6 Pi, 6 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-6 Pi, 6 Pi}, {-5, 5}}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {HoldForm[z], T}, 
LabelStyle -> 
 Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "CMUSerif", 
 FontSlant -> "Plain"]]
```

When plot saved as .eps then pdf generated form is 
[image]

Howeve I want T as
[image]

which I wrote in Miktex using

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

and

```
{$\mathcal{T}$.
```

Can not figure out which kind of T should be used in Mathematica for this purpose.

Also want to find what should be font style for

```
$\mathbf[T]$
```

For the same package used in Miktex

Comment: Would it be possible to install the font as a system accessible type? You could try [this one](http://www.ffonts.net/jsMath-cmsy10.font).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you want is script style. You can enter letters in that style in two ways: For example,

```
\[ScriptCapitalT]
```

> $\mathcal{T}$

or alternatively by the keyboard commands

> <kbd>ESC</kbd>scT<kbd>ESC</kbd>

Other letters would be entered in complete analogy by replacing `T` witht the letter you want.

All the available glyphs are found in the "special Characters" palette that you can open from the "Basic Math Assistant" palette under "All Special Symbols and Characters".

Comment: Thank you. Please can you giude about the other part of the question what if I want font for \mathbf in Miktex?

Comment: If I generalize, how can I see all the available fonts in Mathematica for a given letter?

Comment: The boldface part is trivial: just make the input boldface and (if desired) toggle italic. The keyboard shortcuts for this are the same as in most other application but that depends on your operating system. Maybe it's best to refer you to this link: [Mathematical Typesetting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html)